# Java program that uses SQL - compile into .jar

Tags: java, sql, jar

My code compiles and runs fine in Eclipse, but when I try to make it into a .jar it gives me a bunch of errors.

The code, the .bat file I use to compile into .jar and my error message can be found here:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;


public class Main
{
        private static Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

        public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception
        {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                Main main = new Main();
                int choice = 0;

                System.out.println("\t\tWelcome !\n\n");

                System.out.print(
                                           "1. Get Data From the table \"testtable\"\n"+
                                           "2. Insert data into the table \"testtable\"\n"+
                                           "Your choice?: "
                                                  );
                choice = scn.nextInt();
                scn.nextLine();

                switch( choice )
                {
                case 1:
                        main.getInfo();
                        break;

                case 2:
                        main.insertInfo();
                        break;

                default:
                        System.out.print("Was neither 1 or 2. Terminating program...");
                }


        }

        private void getInfo() throws Exception
        {
                //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb", "guest", "shahin33");
                PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM testtable");
                ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

                System.out.println();

                System.out.println("USERNAME\tPASSWORD");
                while( result.next() )
                {
                        System.out.println(result.getString(1) + "\t\t" + result.getString(2));
                }

                result.close();
                con.close();
        }

        private void insertInfo() throws Exception
        {
                System.out.print("\nUsername: ");
                String username = scn.nextLine();

                System.out.print("Password: ");
                String password = scn.nextLine().toLowerCase();

                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb", "guest", "shahin33");
                PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO testtable VALUES(?,?)");
                statement.setString(1, username);
                statement.setString(2, password);
                statement.executeUpdate();

                System.out.println("\nUser information has been inserted to the database.\nRun the program again and chose 1 to see result.");
                statement.close();
                con.close();

        }
}
```

The .bat file I use to compile into a .jar:

```
@echo off

set /p fileName="Name for the file? Exclude .jar: "

copy *.java "Source Code"
javac *.java

jar -cvfm %fileName%.jar manifest.txt *.class "Source Code"

del *.class /f /q
del "Source Code" /f /q
```

My error message:

```
C:\Users\shahin\Desktop\JavaComp>Compile_N_Whatnot.bat
Name for the file? Exclude .jar: comonXXXXXX
Main.java
        1 fil(er) kopierad(e).
Main.java:5: error: package com.mysql.jdbc does not exist
import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
                     ^
Main.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
                PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) con.prepa
tement("SELECT * FROM testtable");
                ^
  symbol:   class PreparedStatement
  location: class Main
Main.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
                PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) con.prepa
tement("SELECT * FROM testtable");
                                               ^
  symbol:   class PreparedStatement
  location: class Main
Main.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
                PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) con.prepa
tement("INSERT INTO testtable VALUES(?,?)");
                ^
  symbol:   class PreparedStatement
  location: class Main
Main.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
                PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) con.prepa
tement("INSERT INTO testtable VALUES(?,?)");
```

My classpath:

```
C:\Program\Java\jdk1.7.\bin\;
C:\Users\shahin\Desktop\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18\com\mysql\jdbc\;
C:\Users\shahin\Desktop\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up the classpath to include the required jar files. At the least, the JDBC driver is not on the compilation classpath.

I'd strongly recommend not using batch files for this in all but the *most* simple situations, at the least aim for an [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) build script. It knows a lot about how Java stuff is supposed to work, and makes these kinds of problems easier to solve.

Comment: I have the jdbc driver in my classpath

Comment: @user1021085 I doubt it, or you wouldn't get that error. Set it explicitly in the batch file. Why do you copy the source files?

Comment: My classpath includes:
C:\Users\shahin\Desktop\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18\com\mysql\jdbc\
I have it there.
I copy the source files because I want to have the source code in the jar, so friends will be able to check the source code.

Comment: @user1021085 You need to explicitly name the jar, or use a wildcard if you're using JDK6 +.

Comment: Thank you. It works now.
I have another question, though.
Do I need to do the "Class.forName" in every method connecting to a DB?

Comment: @user1021085 Nope, just when the program starts up. Remember to accept answers so future visitors with similar problems know the cause/cure!

Comment: It seems I get an error trying to run the jar..
C:\Users\shahin\Desktop\JavaComp>Run_Me.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driv
er

Comment: @user1021085 You also need to have the correct classpath when you run it.

Comment: Hm? C:\Users\shahin\Desktop\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar  is in my class path

Comment: @user1021085 Then either that space isn't a typo, you're missing a dependency, or you're not using the classpath you think you are. Good luck!

Comment: That was a typo. Not using the classpath I think I am? There's just one??

Comment: @user1021085 There's the compilation classpath, there's an execution classpath. I can't see over your shoulder to know how you're running the code, how you're setting up the environment, if the driver's library requirements are met, etc. You have a classpath issue.

Comment: @user1021085 paste the batch file and *actual* classpath into the question, i.e., paste in shell output. And accept the answer, we're already out of its scope.

Comment: I wrote the contents of my classpath into the question.

Comment: @user1021085 Don't know why the Java bin directory is there, or an older version of the JDBC connector. In any case, when you're running your code, the connector jar isn't your classpath. That's why I asked for a *complete* description of how you're running your code, actual cut-and-paste proof that it's on your classpath, etc. Either way, you need to ask a new question, providing that same information, because we're beyond the scope of your original question.